# Extending on-premises Active Directory for virtual machine

Tags: azure

We currently have an off-shore resource tunneling into a physical machine from the other side of the world, and we're finding that productivity is being impacted.

I've done some reading on the Azure site, but I'm wondering if someone could tell me directly whether my thought is feasible or not. I'd like to extend our Active Directory into Azure, and have the offshore resource work in an Azure Virtual Machine based off a corporate image. We'd like this user to be able to access network resources like file shares, web servers, TFS, etc... My thought is that the resource will be able to work more efficiently off an Azure VM as his node will be closer.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically absolutely possible, what you target is not allowed by the licensing party.

In order to fully achieve your goal, you will need a fully licensed RDS (Remote Desktop Services). Which currently does not cover any public cloud environments.

You can check more on [VM FAQ section here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/). What you need is "RDS", check it there and do regular checks on that page, because this might change in the future.